# How change to the next Video flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating a video player in flutter, I need to know when the video ends to play the next one, I have found several examples but they have not worked for me

this is my code

```
 //Init state

_videoController = VideoPlayerController.network(
      _urlVideo ?? 'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4'
    );
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoController,
      aspectRatio: 3/2,
      autoPlay: false,
      looping: true,
      allowFullScreen: true,
      cupertinoProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a listener

```dart
_videoController = VideoPlayerController.network(
      _urlVideo ?? 'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4'
    );
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoController,
      aspectRatio: 3/2,
      autoPlay: false,
      looping: true,
      allowFullScreen: true,
      cupertinoProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(),
    )..addListener((){

    //do anything you want with _chewieController in listener. for example :
       if(_chewieController.videoPlayerController.value.position == finalPosition){
           var _position = _chewieController.videoPlayerController.value.position;
           var _duration = _chewieController.videoPlayerController.value.duration;
           if(_duration?.compareTo(_position) == 0 || _duration?.compareTo(_position) == -1){
              _playOtherVideo();
           }
       }  
    });
```

Comment: How do I get the final position of the video ?, I tried to do this for days, however it gives me null the duration element

Comment: @AndresCuello I updated the answer also checkout this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21929

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `loop:false`,

Then when it play finished, fire another `play` with the next video.

And do the things you want in that finished event if you want.